# What's the significance of the antagonists' downfall in "The Knowing"?

Tags: the-knowing, sharon-cameron

As the title would indicate: **SPOILERS FOR THE ENDING**.

I walked away from my first re-read in a while of *The Knowing* satisfied, but upon thinking about the ending I'm rather confused at how it all went down. Or rather, not *what happened* but *what it's supposed to mean/show*. From my reading, the main characters don't end up affecting how the two main sets of antagonists (Commander Faye's faction and the NWSE led by Lian Archiva) meet their ends. An absurdly quick summary:

Faye brings her people to attack New Canaan, but Lian instead offers surrender on the condition that the formalities be conducted in the old city, where Lian knows that the Forgetting trees will soon release their spores. At the appointed time both Faye's people and Lian's NWSE, along with Beckett, are in the old city. Samara swoops down an airbike, people monologue and exposit at each other, and then Samara and Beckett get outta Dodge before the spores come. In the end, Faye's people lose because in the chaos of Forgetting most of them die (likely at each other's hands), and Lian's people lose because they've given themselves "immunity" to the Forgetting spores, which they think will prevent Forgetting but actually means instead of Forgetting they die on exposure.

How is this a satisfying resolution of the story, though? Both groups literally cause their own demise, which seems like it should be meaningful, but I can't put my finger on why. It's poetic justice, but how is it poetic? What meaning can be extracted from this particular method of demise, where the only thing the main characters do to change the overall outcome is save each other?

What's the significance of the antagonists' downfall in *The Knowing*?